# Sql Server Conditional And Clause

Tags: sql-server

How can i write a query like with @date parameter from user

```
select * from table where

if @date = 'FUTURE' then dbDate > CURRENT_TIMESTAMP 
else if @date = 'Past' then dbDate < CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

thanks

Comment: This pattern (which you only make visible as comments) is very common - discussions here as [kitchen sink example](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/backtobasics-updated-kitchen-sink-example) and [dynamic search conditions](http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if @date = 'FUTURE'
    select * from table where dbDate > CURRENT_TIMESTAMP 
else 
    select * from table where dbDate < CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

or

```
select * from table 
where (@date = 'FUTURE' and dbDate > CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
    OR (@date = 'past' and dbDate < CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
```

Comment: Ivan if select statement is more complex and bigger and also has more parameters then should use same like you replied?

Comment: cannot use case with in one select?

Comment: Using `CASE` in `WHERE` is possible but is unnecessary for given conditions. If many  parameters then option two is for you.